# MSVC /arch:[instruction set] - SSE3, AVX, AVX2

Tags: visual-c++, simd, avx

Here is an example of a class which shows supported instruction sets. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx

I want to write three different implementations of a single function, each of them using different instruction set. But due to flag /ARCH:AVX2, for example, this app won't ever run anywhere but on 4th+ generation of Intel processors, so the whole point of checking is pointless.

So, question is: what *exactly* this flag does? Enables *support* or enables *compiler optimizations using provided instruction sets*?

In other words, can I completely remove this flag and keep using functions from immintrin.h, emmintrin.h, etc?

Comment: There is no SSE3 option in MSVC.  In 64-bit mode the only options are `AVX` and `AVX2`.  The main point of `AVX` is to tell MSVC to use vex encoded instructions. I don't really know the point of `AVX2`. I think it's mostly for optimizing from FMA3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An using of option /ARCH:AVX2 allows to use YMM registers and AVX2 instructions of CPU by the best way. But if CPU is not support these instruction it will be a program crash. If you use AVX2 instructions and compiler flag /ARCH:SSE2  that will be a decreasing of performance (about 2x times).

So the best implementation when every implementation of your function is compiled with corresponding compiler options (/ARCH:AVX2,  /ARCH:SSE2 and so on). The easiest way to do it - put your implementations (scalar, SSE, AVX) in different files and compile each file with specific compiler options.

Also it will be a good idea if you create a separate file  where you can check CPU abilities and call corresponding implementation of your function.

There is an example of a [library](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd) which does CPU [checking](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd/blob/master/src/Simd/SimdEnable.h) and [calling](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd/blob/master/src/Simd/SimdLib.cpp) an one of implemented function.

Comment: So, did I understand right, that, basically, my needs are: create, say 3 libraries with their own implementations(and corresponding ARCH flags), then check processor capabilities, and then link with them all at once?

Comment: Yes. You can create 3 libraries (each of these has its own compiler options). Also you could set individual compiler options for every file inside one library (Visual Studio allows to do this).

Comment: Thanks! Refactored a bit, according to the advice, now it works!