# Benchmarking GCC 7 vs VS2017 using Nbody test

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, gcc7

The code is taken from [Computer Benchmarks Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=nbody&lang=gpp&id=8) and pasted below.

I modified to use SSE2 instead of SSE3 since MSVC does not support beyond SSE2. In particular, I replaced the header file "immintrin.h" to "emmintrin.h"

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <array>

constexpr double PI(3.141592653589793);
constexpr double SOLAR_MASS ( 4 * PI * PI );
constexpr double DAYS_PER_YEAR(365.24);

struct body {
  double x[3], fill, v[3], mass;
  constexpr body(double x0, double x1, double x2, double v0, double v1, double v2,  double Mass):
    x{x0,x1,x2}, fill(0), v{v0,v1,v2}, mass(Mass) {}
};

class N_Body_System
{
  static std::array<body,5> bodies;

  void offset_momentum()
  {
    unsigned int k;
    for(auto &body: bodies)
      for(k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
        bodies[0].v[k] -= body.v[k] * body.mass / SOLAR_MASS;
  }

public:
  N_Body_System()
  {
    offset_momentum();
  }
  void advance(double dt)
  {
    constexpr unsigned int N = ((bodies.size() - 1) * bodies.size()) / 2;

    static double r[N][4];
    static double mag[N];

    unsigned int i, m;
    __m128d dx[3], dsquared, distance, dmag;

    i=0;
    for(auto bi(bodies.begin()); bi!=bodies.end(); ++bi)
      {
        auto bj(bi);
        for(++bj; bj!=bodies.end(); ++bj, ++i)
          for (m=0; m<3; ++m)
            r[i][m] = bi->x[m] - bj->x[m];
      }

    for (i=0; i<N; i+=2)
      {
        for (m=0; m<3; ++m)
          {
            dx[m] = _mm_loadl_pd(dx[m], &r[i][m]);
            dx[m] = _mm_loadh_pd(dx[m], &r[i+1][m]);
          }

        dsquared = dx[0] * dx[0] + dx[1] * dx[1] + dx[2] * dx[2];
        distance = _mm_cvtps_pd(_mm_rsqrt_ps(_mm_cvtpd_ps(dsquared)));

        for (m=0; m<2; ++m)
          distance = distance * _mm_set1_pd(1.5)
            - ((_mm_set1_pd(0.5) * dsquared) * distance)
            * (distance * distance);

        dmag = _mm_set1_pd(dt) / (dsquared) * distance;
        _mm_store_pd(&mag[i], dmag);
      }

    i=0;
    for(auto bi(bodies.begin()); bi!=bodies.end(); ++bi)
      {
        auto bj(bi);
        for(++bj; bj!=bodies.end(); ++bj, ++i)
          for(m=0; m<3; ++m)
            {
              const double x = r[i][m] * mag[i];
              bi->v[m] -= x * bj->mass;
              bj->v[m] += x * bi->mass;
            }
      }

    for(auto &body: bodies)
      for(m=0; m<3; ++m)
        body.x[m] += dt * body.v[m];
  }

  double energy()
  {
    double e(0.0);
    for(auto bi(bodies.cbegin()); bi!=bodies.cend(); ++bi)
      {
        e += bi->mass * ( bi->v[0] * bi->v[0]
                          + bi->v[1] * bi->v[1]
                          + bi->v[2] * bi->v[2] ) / 2.;

        auto bj(bi);
        for(++bj; bj!=bodies.end(); ++bj)
          {
            double distance = 0;
            for(auto k=0; k<3; ++k)
            {
              const double dx = bi->x[k] - bj->x[k];
              distance += dx * dx;
            }

            e -= (bi->mass * bj->mass) / std::sqrt(distance);
          }
      }
    return e;
  }
};


std::array<body,5> N_Body_System::bodies{{
    /* sun */
    body(0., 0., 0. ,
         0., 0., 0. ,
         SOLAR_MASS),
    /* jupiter */
    body(4.84143144246472090e+00,
         -1.16032004402742839e+00,
         -1.03622044471123109e-01 ,
         1.66007664274403694e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         7.69901118419740425e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         -6.90460016972063023e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR ,
         9.54791938424326609e-04 * SOLAR_MASS
         ),
    /* saturn */
    body(8.34336671824457987e+00,
         4.12479856412430479e+00,
         -4.03523417114321381e-01 ,
         -2.76742510726862411e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         4.99852801234917238e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         2.30417297573763929e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR ,
         2.85885980666130812e-04 * SOLAR_MASS
         ),
    /* uranus */
    body(1.28943695621391310e+01,
         -1.51111514016986312e+01,
         -2.23307578892655734e-01 ,
         2.96460137564761618e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         2.37847173959480950e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         -2.96589568540237556e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR ,
         4.36624404335156298e-05 * SOLAR_MASS
         ),
    /* neptune */
    body(1.53796971148509165e+01,
         -2.59193146099879641e+01,
         1.79258772950371181e-01 ,
         2.68067772490389322e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         1.62824170038242295e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         -9.51592254519715870e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR ,
         5.15138902046611451e-05 * SOLAR_MASS
         )
  }};

int main(int , char** argv)
{
  int i, n = atoi(argv[1]);
  N_Body_System system;

  printf("%.9f\n", system.energy());
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    system.advance(0.01);
  printf("%.9f\n", system.energy());

  return 0;
}
```

I then discovered that the code is using GCC extension of SSE arithmatics, so I replaced the +-*/ with __mm_[add/sub/mul/div]_pd in MSVC version. Namely from

```
        dsquared = dx[0] * dx[0] + dx[1] * dx[1] + dx[2] * dx[2];
        distance = _mm_cvtps_pd(_mm_rsqrt_ps(_mm_cvtpd_ps(dsquared)));

        for (m=0; m<2; ++m)
          distance = distance * _mm_set1_pd(1.5)
            - ((_mm_set1_pd(0.5) * dsquared) * distance)
            * (distance * distance);

        dmag = _mm_set1_pd(dt) / (dsquared) * distance;
        _mm_store_pd(&mag[i], dmag);
      }
```

to

```
        dsquared = _mm_add_pd(_mm_add_pd(_mm_mul_pd(dx[0], dx[0]), _mm_mul_pd(dx[1], dx[1])), _mm_mul_pd(dx[2], dx[2]));
        distance = _mm_cvtps_pd(_mm_rsqrt_ps(_mm_cvtpd_ps(dsquared)));

        for (m = 0; m<2; ++m)
            distance = _mm_sub_pd(_mm_mul_pd(distance,  _mm_set1_pd(1.5)),
            _mm_mul_pd(_mm_mul_pd(_mm_mul_pd(_mm_set1_pd(0.5), dsquared), distance),
            _mm_mul_pd(distance, distance)));

        dmag = _mm_mul_pd(_mm_div_pd(_mm_set1_pd(dt), (dsquared)), distance);
        _mm_store_pd(&mag[i], dmag);
    }
```

I compiled the GCC(mingw-w64) version using

```
g++ -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native -ffast-math -mfpmath=sse -msse2 --std=c++14 1.cpp
```

and VS2017 cli args look like this

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS- /Qpar /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:fast /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_MBCS" /fp:except- /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:SSE2 /Gd /Oy /Oi /MT /std:c++14 /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Ot /Fp"x64\Release\ConsoleApplication1.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

I have also turned on /LTCG in linker options. I then run both versions 100,000,000 times on my i7-4720HQ, 12G laptop.

The GCC version fluctuates between 7500ms to 8500ms, whereas the VS version consistently takes more than 10,000ms and averages at 12,000+ms.

Is there any plausible explanation to this performance difference before diving into disassembly?

Comment: The options don't really make for a fair comparison. Anyway, a factor < 2 between 2 compilers on one specific microbenchmark is not that unusual.

Comment: who told you that `MSVC does not support beyond SSE2`? It already has [support for AVX-2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39484264/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It does support AVX and AVX2 years ago but not SSE3 SSE4

Answer (score 0):

I think, you might have some misunderstanding of some GCC flags. Let's just run through your list:

- `-O3` - enable (almost) all available optimizations
- `-fomit-frame-pointer` - use `RBP` as a general-purpose register. Redundant (implied by `-O3`)
- `-march=native` - use the instruction set available on the host machine (i.e. up to AVX2 for your i7-4720HQ), implies `-mtune=native`.
- `-ffast-math` - allow some non-standard-conforming FP optimizations (should be useful here)
- `-mfpmath=sse` - use SSE (or AVX if available) instructions instead of x87. Redundant (default for 64-bit architectures)
- `-msse2` - allow using SSE2 instructions. Redundant (implied by `-march=native`).

In fact, GCC is allowed to use any SSE (1 - 4.2) and AVX/AVX2 instructions and will even tune the code to make it work faster on your particular CPU.

If you really want to force GCC to use only SSE2, try something like `-march=core2`.

P.S. Now it's time to dive into disassembly.

Comment: So it seems MSVC is limited to SSE2 (By the flags chosen) while GCC can use up to AVX2, is that right?

Answer (score -1):

Are you turning off checked iterators in the Visual studio version?  By default VC++ uses checked iterators even in release builds. You need #define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0 to disable them.

Comment: I added your macro on top of the source file and it did make it a little faster, but the improvement is generally less than 1s out of 12s total average run time.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @juanchopanza Actually I was thinking it would be the beginning of a wiki answer.  There are probably a dozen different settings that need to be touched in Visual studio to get good code out of it.